# Para que sirve Convert.ToSingle

Tags: c#

Estoy revisando un algoritmo ya creado, para entender como hacer una función que devuelva el promedio de tres notas, pero me gustaría saber que hace con el conver.tosingle

```
promedio = Convert.ToSingle((nota1 * 0.35) + (nota2 * 0.35) + (nota3 * 0.30));
```

Comment: Hola Jorge, has mirado [la documentacion del metodo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.convert.tosingle(v=vs.110).aspx) para saber que hace?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque se puede revisar la documentación y obtener la respuesta

Comment: Antes de votar esta pregunta por favor lean esto https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2746/2027

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convierte un tipo de dato `string`, `int16`, `int32`, `int64`, `float`, `double`, `char`, `bool`, `Datetime` a tipo single Single.

Es bueno notar que `Single` y `float` son los mismos, no hay diferencia entre ambos.

```
Single s = 11;
float f = 22;
s = f; // valido
f = s; // valido
```

`Single` fue un tipo de dato introducido por microsoft mientras que `float` se dejo para que a los programadores que migraran de [c](/questions/tagged/c) les sea mas facil la transicion por el tipo de dato float en `c`. Digamos que el tipo `float` es un alias para `Single`.

Comment: Explicacion? Porque el voto negativo?

Comment: No voté pero puede que tenga que ver con que la pregunta se resuelve leyendo la documentacion, sin más intringuilis que ese

Comment: `Single` no es un alias de `float`. `float` es el alias en C# del struct `System.Single` de .NET

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz tienes razon lo escribi al revez, debi de haberme confundido. Gracias.

Comment: Einer, los tipos de datos deberías escribirlos en mayúsculas si te refieres a los nombres de clases y structs de .NET y en minúsculas si te refieres a los alias de C#. En tu respuesta todo está en minúscula pero están mezclados los nombres de clases con alias

Answer (score 1):

La clase `Convert` ([Referencia](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.convert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) provee métodos para convertir datos.

De acuerdo a los [comentarios en su código fuente](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,fc990bd1275d43d6), las conversiones se pueden realizar de acuerdo a esta tabla:

```
// From:  To: Bol Chr SBy Byt I16 U16 I32 U32 I64 U64 Sgl Dbl Dec Dat Str
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Boolean     x       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
// Char            x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x                   x
// SByte       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
// Byte        x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
// Int16       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
// UInt16      x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
// Int32       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
// UInt32      x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
// Int64       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
// UInt64      x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
// Single      x       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
// Double      x       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
// Decimal     x       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
// DateTime                                                        x   x
// String      x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Por otro lado, el tipo `Single` ([Referencia](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/system.single(v=vs.110).aspx)) en C# es lo que en otros lenguajes como Java se interpreta como `float`: un número de punto flotante de precisión .

Por lo tanto [`Convert.ToSingle`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1c5255ca394e755d) es un método que convierte datos de los tipos `bool`, `SByte`, `byte`, `int` (y variaciones), `double`, `decimal` y `string` al tipo de dato `Single` o "float".

Answer (score 1):

Convierte el valor del número decimal especificado a un número float de precision sencilla, es decir, los números muy grandes te los va a mostrar en tipo sencillo:

Ejemplo:

```
result = Convert.ToSingle(Decimal.MinValue);

//El valor de Decimal.MinValue = '-79228162514264337593543950335'
//El resultado 'result' de esta operación és: '-7.922816E+28'
```

[Página con ejemplos.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/e99y3aec(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

El método ToSingle intenta convertir el valor pasado como parámetro a un Numero Flotante de precisión simple es decir un número en este rango :

1.5 × 10^45 a 3.4 × 10^38 con una precision de 7 digitos

Si usaras ToDouble sería un flotante de presicion doble :

Aproximadamente 5.0 × 10^324 a 1.7 × 10^308 con precision de 15-16 digitos.

El estandar que rige estos tipos es el de formatos  IEEE 754

Mas información : https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_coma_flotante